# How can I turn this static function into a function that allows arguments?

Tags: javascript

I have a function that prompts for a user inputted date, and a user inputted future date. It then calculates the difference between the two dates, and outputs Days, Hours, Minutes, and Seconds.

I want to make this function accept two arguments, current, and future,
ex: `function calcTime(current, future)`. I then want it to return; the days, hours, minutes, and seconds.

I'm not sure how to do this, and how I would properly format my `calcTime(['2019' '11' '02' '30'], ['2020' '11' '02' '30']);` (or whatever way is best to do this, etc..)

Here's my current function:

```
function calcTime() {
  //user input
  var userYearCurrent = prompt("Enter a year in numbers(2019)", "Enter a year ex: 2019, 2020, 2021");
  var userMonthCurrent = prompt("Enter a month in numbers(1-12), or type a month name", "Enter a month ex: 11, November");
  var userDayCurrent = prompt("Enter a day of The month in mumbers(1-31)", "Enter a day of the month ex: 14, 21");
  var userTimeStringCurrent = prompt("Enter a time (2:05) or if seconds are needed(2:05:30)", "Enter a time of day ex: 11:15, do not use military time");
  //split time
  var userTimeStringCurrentParts = userTimeStringCurrent.split(':');
     if (userTimeStringCurrentParts.length === 2) {
         userTimeStringCurrentParts.push('00'); // empty seconds
     }
     var userHoursCurrent = parseInt(userTimeStringCurrentParts[0]);
     var userMinutesCurrent = parseInt(userTimeStringCurrentParts[1]);
     var userSecondsCurrent = parseInt(userTimeStringCurrentParts[2]);
//user input
  var userYearFuture = prompt("Enter a FUTURE year in numbers(2019)", "Enter a year ex: 2019, 2020, 2021");
  var userMonthFuture = prompt("Enter a FUTURE month in numbers(1-12), or type a month name", "Enter a month ex: 11, November");
  var userDayFuture = prompt("Enter a FUTURE day of The month in mumbers(1-31)", "Enter a day of the month ex: 14, 21");
  var userTimeStringFuture = prompt("Enter a FUTURE time (2:05) or if seconds are needed(2:05:30)", "Enter a time of day ex: 11:15, do not use military time");
//split time
  var userTimeStringFutureParts = userTimeStringFuture.split(':');
      if (userTimeStringFutureParts.length === 2) {
          userTimeStringFutureParts.push('00'); // empty seconds
      }

  var userHoursFuture = parseInt(userTimeStringFutureParts[0]);
  var userMinutesFuture = parseInt(userTimeStringFutureParts[1]);
  var userSecondsFuture = parseInt(userTimeStringFutureParts[2]);

  var dateCurrent = new Date(userYearCurrent, userMonthCurrent, userDayCurrent, userHoursCurrent, userMinutesCurrent, userSecondsCurrent);
  var dateFuture = new Date(userYearFuture, userMonthFuture, userDayFuture, userHoursFuture, userMinutesFuture, userSecondsFuture);


  var mathSeconds = Math.abs(dateFuture.getTime() - dateCurrent.getTime()) / 1000;
  var days = Math.floor(mathSeconds / 86400);
  mathSeconds -= days * 86400;
  var hours = Math.floor(mathSeconds / 3600) % 24;
  mathSeconds -= hours * 3600;
  var minutes = Math.floor(mathSeconds / 60) % 60;
  mathSeconds -= minutes * 60;
  var seconds = mathSeconds;

  document.getElementById("time1").innerHTML = "Time between your two dates: " + days + " Days: " + hours + " Hours: " + minutes + " Minutes: " + seconds + " Seconds";
}
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: You could add the parameters and check if they're initialized or not, and based on that proceed with corresponding logic

Comment: @shrys I tried doing something like this:

```function calcTime(current, future) {
  
  var userYearCurrent = (current[0] || prompt("Enter a year in numbers(2019)", "Enter a year ex: 2019, 2020, 2021"));```

But it did not work, can you clarify?

Comment: that may throw error you might want to check with `typeof current == "undefined"` condition

Comment: `typeof current == "undefined" && current[0] ? current[0] : prompt("Enter a year in numbers(2019)", "Enter a year ex: 2019, 2020, 2021")`

Comment: Noob question as I'm new to javascript, but is that the exact way the code is supposed to be, or is that somewhat pseudo code and there's supposed to be an if(typeof current ==  
?  I tried the code above exactly and it doesn't do anything

```var userYearCurrent = typeof current == "undefined" && current[0] ? current[0] : prompt("Enter a year in numbers(2019)", "Enter a year ex: 2019, 2020, 2021")```

Comment: really sorry the condition would `typeof current != "undefined"` as we're checking if it not `undefined`

Comment: [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shrys/aLk84ruy/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the function like this
calcTime('14/9/2019','14/9/2020')

```
function calcTime(currentdate,futuredate) {
            // var currentdate = '14/9/2019';
            // var futuredate = '14/9/2020';
            var userCurrentDatePart = currentdate.split('/');
            var userFutureDatePart = futuredate.split('/');
      //user input
      var userYearCurrent = userCurrentDatePart[2];
      var userMonthCurrent = userCurrentDatePart[1];
      var userDayCurrent = userCurrentDatePart[0];
      var userTimeStringCurrent = '0:0';
      //split time
      var userTimeStringCurrentParts = userTimeStringCurrent.split(':');
         if (userTimeStringCurrentParts.length === 2) {
             userTimeStringCurrentParts.push('00'); // empty seconds
         }
         var userHoursCurrent = parseInt(userTimeStringCurrentParts[0]);
         var userMinutesCurrent = parseInt(userTimeStringCurrentParts[1]);
         var userSecondsCurrent = parseInt(userTimeStringCurrentParts[2]);
    //user input
      var userYearFuture = userFutureDatePart[2];
      var userMonthFuture = userFutureDatePart[1];
      var userDayFuture = userFutureDatePart[0];
      var userTimeStringFuture = '23:59';
    //split time
      var userTimeStringFutureParts = userTimeStringFuture.split(':');
          if (userTimeStringFutureParts.length === 2) {
              userTimeStringFutureParts.push('00'); // empty seconds
          }

      var userHoursFuture = parseInt(userTimeStringFutureParts[0]);
      var userMinutesFuture = parseInt(userTimeStringFutureParts[1]);
      var userSecondsFuture = parseInt(userTimeStringFutureParts[2]);

      var dateCurrent = new Date(userYearCurrent, userMonthCurrent, userDayCurrent, userHoursCurrent, userMinutesCurrent, userSecondsCurrent);
      var dateFuture = new Date(userYearFuture, userMonthFuture, userDayFuture, userHoursFuture, userMinutesFuture, userSecondsFuture);


      var mathSeconds = Math.abs(dateFuture.getTime() - dateCurrent.getTime()) / 1000;
      var days = Math.floor(mathSeconds / 86400);
      mathSeconds -= days * 86400;
      var hours = Math.floor(mathSeconds / 3600) % 24;
      mathSeconds -= hours * 3600;
      var minutes = Math.floor(mathSeconds / 60) % 60;
      mathSeconds -= minutes * 60;
      var seconds = mathSeconds;

      document.getElementById("time1").innerHTML = "Time between your two dates: " + days + " Days: " + hours + " Hours: " + minutes + " Minutes: " + seconds + " Seconds";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! How would you pass the time in minutes and seconds in, ex: calcTime('14/9/2019/02:30:45','14/9/2020/05:24:30')

Comment: just change 
var userTimeStringCurrent = '0:0'; to
var userTimeStringCurrent = userCurrentDatePart[3]; 
and 
var userTimeStringFuture = '23:59';  to 
var userTimeStringFuture = userFutureDatePart[3];

Comment: Thanks, i tried that and put the array backwards on accident, it works now. Thanks, yours is the only solution that has worked so far without any problems

Answer (score 0):

There are surely better ways to implement this, but in your case you could to something like using the prompts as fallback values for your missing date parts:

```js
function calcTime(currentDate=[], futureDate=[]) {
  const [
   userYearCurrent = prompt("Enter a year in numbers(2019)", "Enter a year ex: 2019, 2020, 2021"),
  userMonthCurrent = prompt("Enter a month in numbers(1-12), or type a month name", "Enter a month ex: 11, November"),
  userDayCurrent = prompt("Enter a day of The month in mumbers(1-31)", "Enter a day of the month ex: 14, 21"),
  userTimeStringCurrent = prompt("Enter a time (2:05) or if seconds are needed(2:05:30)", "Enter a time of day ex: 11:15, do not use military time")
  ] = currentDate;
  const [
    userYearFuture = prompt("Enter a FUTURE year in numbers(2019)", "Enter a year ex: 2019, 2020, 2021"),
    userMonthFuture = prompt("Enter a FUTURE month in numbers(1-12), or type a month name", "Enter a month ex: 11, November"),
    userDayFuture = prompt("Enter a FUTURE day of The month in mumbers(1-31)", "Enter a day of the month ex: 14, 21"),
    userTimeStringFuture = prompt("Enter a FUTURE time (2:05) or if seconds are needed(2:05:30)", "Enter a time of day ex: 11:15, do not use military time")
   ] = futureDate;
   
  //split time
  var userTimeStringCurrentParts = userTimeStringCurrent.split(':');
     if (userTimeStringCurrentParts.length === 2) {
         userTimeStringCurrentParts.push('00'); // empty seconds
     }
     var userHoursCurrent = parseInt(userTimeStringCurrentParts[0]);
     var userMinutesCurrent = parseInt(userTimeStringCurrentParts[1]);
     var userSecondsCurrent = parseInt(userTimeStringCurrentParts[2]);
//user input

//split time
  var userTimeStringFutureParts = userTimeStringFuture.split(':');
      if (userTimeStringFutureParts.length === 2) {
          userTimeStringFutureParts.push('00'); // empty seconds
      }

  var userHoursFuture = parseInt(userTimeStringFutureParts[0]);
  var userMinutesFuture = parseInt(userTimeStringFutureParts[1]);
  var userSecondsFuture = parseInt(userTimeStringFutureParts[2]);

  var dateCurrent = new Date(userYearCurrent, userMonthCurrent, userDayCurrent, userHoursCurrent, userMinutesCurrent, userSecondsCurrent);
  var dateFuture = new Date(userYearFuture, userMonthFuture, userDayFuture, userHoursFuture, userMinutesFuture, userSecondsFuture);


  var mathSeconds = Math.abs(dateFuture.getTime() - dateCurrent.getTime()) / 1000;
  var days = Math.floor(mathSeconds / 86400);
  mathSeconds -= days * 86400;
  var hours = Math.floor(mathSeconds / 3600) % 24;
  mathSeconds -= hours * 3600;
  var minutes = Math.floor(mathSeconds / 60) % 60;
  mathSeconds -= minutes * 60;
  var seconds = mathSeconds;

  return "Time between your two dates: " + days + " Days: " + hours + " Hours: " + minutes + " Minutes: " + seconds + " Seconds";
}

console.log(calcTime(['2019','09','03','00:00'], ['2019','09',undefined,'00:00']));
```

Comment: The order inside each date array is important though

Comment: I do not understand why the prompt only appears when a value is not passed. I do not see any conditional parts in the code. Can someone explain me how is this working?

Comment: The prompt function is just a function that returns a value. In this case I just call it if a particular value is undefined and use its return value as default value.

Comment: The rest is just the new array spread syntax. Given `var array = [ 1 ];`, doing this `var [ firstITem ] = array;` is the same as doing this: `var firstItem = array[0];`

Comment: But with the spread syntax you can also define default values `var [ firstItem=0 ] = array` is the same as `var firstItem = array[0] || 0`

Comment: @giuseppedeponte Thanks! For some reason the code does not run when I press the button, nothing happens at all (chrome browser)```<button onclick="calcTime(['2019','09','03','00:00'], ['2019','09','05','00:00'])">Display</button>```

When i leave the 05 as undefined, the code DOES run when clicking the button, but it asks for all the prompts instead of taking the values from the function call

Edit: it only asks for one prompt as well, the month.

Comment: Your calcTime function returns a value now, but does not use it to update the DOM. It should work if, instead of returning the string, you add it as innerHtml of an element. You can see [here](https://codepen.io/giuseppedeponte/pen/dyybyBe)